How to update a column in an Excel file on a Microsoft365 drive using ASP.NET Core Web API without Azure or Microsoft Graph API?
I need to create an ASP.NET Core Web API that updates a column in an Excel file. The Excel file is stored on a network drive, not locally. Most solutions I've found suggest using Azure AD and Microsoft Graph API for this purpose. However, my organization doesn't have the necessary licenses for Azure or Microsoft Graph API.
Is there a way to achieve this without relying on Azure or Microsoft Graph API? What libraries or approaches can I use to update an Excel file located on a network drive using .NET Core?
Any examples or detailed guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried to use Open XML cause I found that it doesn't require A licence for Excel to work, but I had no chance to connect to the Excel that already exists on my working drive!

Did you try OfficeOpenXml nuget? if you can download the Excel from the drive and upload again, maybe this nuget can help you.
For use that library you must add this to your web config:
<add key="EPPlus:ExcelPackage.LicenseContext" value="NonCommercial" />

This is an example of how to use the nuget:
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;

public void UpdateExcelFile(string filePath)
{
    // Load the Excel file
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
        if (worksheet != null)
        {
            // Update a column in the first worksheet
            for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = "Updated Value";
            }
            // Save the changes
            package.Save();
        }
    }
}

